# Dijkstra path weight

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

[image: Dijkstra]

Why would some paths have significantly more / less weights than other equal length paths? In Dijkstra's do length and path weight not equate?

Comment: Do you by any chance mean edges when you say paths?

Comment: How did you generate that graphic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean that the graphical representation of the `graph` doesn't correspond to the `weight` each path has ?

They don't have too... the visual representation is just a representation, nothing else. It isn't oblied be equivalent of the weight.

You could redraw the graph anyway you like, just making sure that the connections between the vertices are kept.

Edit: and it doesn't matter what kind of graph you're dealing with, be it Dijkstra or any other. You can even fidn graphs where the direction matters: From A to B the weight can be 10 and from B to A the weight can be 30. No problem.

**Edit 2**: the image just shows how the vertices connect to each other. The image doesn't need to be in scale with the graph that is stored in your program. Sometimes you'll have graphs with so many vertices and edges that you won't be able to represent it in a good way. What matters for your programing problems are the vertices, the edges, and it's weights. The image is just a rough representation of it. You can redraw the image as you like, you just have to make sure to put all vertices, all edges, and all weights for each edge.

Comment: Is it possible with Dijkstra's to equate edges with distance or are they completely separate issues?

Comment: If I understand what you mean: the edges are the distance between two vertices (if you think in a map, like cities in a country). They can also mean "cost" (for example, going from a state "liquid" to a state "vapor" costs 100o Celsius). They can mean anything you like. The edges weight is the price for going from vertice A to vertice B.

Comment: Are there algorithm's / versions of Dijkstra's where the edge is solely the length? I still dont see how / why, in the above example say, travelling between two similar distances "costs" 3 & 16 units.

Comment: @daidai: no, the edge and the length in the image can be different. In some place (in the image, in the program, in a table...) someone says that "going from A to B costs 3, going from B to C costs 16". And that's all. You can redraw the image anyway you like, given that you stil represent the vertices `A, B, C`, and the weights `3 and 16`. You can go from A to B in a straight line, in a curve, in a totally curly way... it doesn't matter. You just need to think that from A to B it costs something, from B to C it has another cost...

Comment: Ah but I want it to be in scale. It is a representation of actual places and their rough distance to that place. Is it possible to use Dijkstra and keep it all to scale?

Comment: Consider that graphs, Dijkstra, etc, is just how you represent it inside your program, or how you calculate something. You can draw the image in any scale you want. So you can draw it with the weight being proportional to the line's lenght. No problem at all. You have to perceive that the graph inside your program has the distances, the drawing can be anyway you like: line's lenght, color, where each point is located.... this is up to you.

Comment: Ha right so Ive just found in the code that the weight was generated randomly, confusing me completely - thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The length of the path (as in the size of the line in the diagram) is irrelevant, it's only to make it look nice.  The weight of the line indicates the cost of travelling between two nodes.

It is confusing though, and you could make length = weight by changing the way the graph is drawn.

Comment: Why would the cost of travelling between two closer points be, for example, 3 times more than another two points? This is what I dont understand.

Comment: @daidai: The distance in the `graph` is specified (the numbers you saw in the graph). The graph doesn't need to be in scale with the real distances. The image you produce to represent the graph just helps you representing it.

Comment: Ah see Im guess Im trying to do the reverse. The plots on the example are representations of places and lines are meant to be the rough distances to them - and Im using this algorithm to find the shortest path between two places, via others. Is the Dijkstra not suitable for my needs?

Comment: You're doing it right. Dijkstra is suitable exactly to do that: find the sortest way between vertices. That's ok. You just can think that the image you have represent the real distance. What matters is the weight in the edges. The shortest path = the one that the added weights is the smaller one. Doesn't matter how many vertices you go through, or how far they are in the image.